# How can i get the Public IP Address of the server where my dotnet worker application is hosted?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, networking, deployment

Is there any way I can get the public IP Address of the server where my application is hosted?

For example:

My use case is that the same server will have the one or more database. If my domain name of the server is `128.232.323.232`(Some value). How can i get this value in my application.

I tried the following approach:

```
        var hostName = Dns.GetHostName();

        // Get the IP addresses associated with the host name
        var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[0];

        // Perform a reverse DNS lookup to get the FQDN
        var hostEntry = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(ipAddress);

        // Access the FQDN
        var fqdn = hostEntry.HostName;

        _logger.LogInformation("Dry IP Address: {DryIP}", (await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(hostName)).AddressList[0]);

        _logger.LogInformation("Dry Host Name: {Name}", hostName);
            
        _logger.LogInformation("Ip Address: {Ipaddress}", ipAddress);

        _logger.LogInformation("FQDN: {fqdn}", fqdn);
```

Result:

```
[16:52:24 INF] 
Dry IP Address: 127.0.1.1

[16:52:24 INF] 
Dry Host Name: hd-ubuntu

[16:52:24 INF] 
Ip Address: 127.0.1.1

[16:52:24 INF] 
FQDN: hd-ubuntu
```

when i deploy it on the test server the result for `Ip address` is `::1`

I can create a function that uses a external api such as `https://httpbin.org/ip`. to get my public Ip address. Is there any way i can do it using pure c# code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core 2.1 get current web hostname and port in Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52741142/asp-net-core-2-1-get-current-web-hostname-and-port-in-startup-cs)

Comment: Where you host your application? IIS or docker or else? How to get hte IP should according to different hosting environment.

Comment: I hosted my application on IIS

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry my question wasn't clear before. Now I have updated it

Comment: Why do you need this? If the client requested under a certain hostname, you can get that from the Request. Why do you need the public IP address?

Comment: Actually I am working on a Worker application. The same instance of worker is deployed on multiple servers. In the server there are multiple databases. Worker reads a message from the rabbit mq and executes the operation if the message contains the same server as the worker's deployed server.