# How to get Request Uri from middleware delegate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am trying to log elapsed time for each request(.net core 2.2) in my configure method like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        Logging.Log.Id = Convert.ToString(new Activity(string.Empty).Id);

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        await next.Invoke();
        sw.Stop();

        Logging.Log.Info($"ElapsedTime: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    });

    // rest of method code omitted 
}
```

Along with elapsed time I want to display which endpoint was called or absolute uri where the request is headed to. How can I get the same here from context object.

Comment: `context.Request.Path`... You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `context` parameter has a `Request` property, which has all the information you could want about which URL the client is calling.

You can follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120222/get-raw-url-from-microsoft-aspnet-http-httprequest) to help you construct a raw url, or just use the pieces that object gives you.