# Fetch Url Segments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to fetch the url segments of the current page. I was using Web Forms earlier. In Web Forms I was using `Request.Url.Segments` method to do that. But this method is not working in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

```
string[] urlSegments = Request.Url.Segments;
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120222/get-raw-url-from-microsoft-aspnet-http-httprequest

Answer (score 6):

[Uri.Segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netframework-4.8) works with .net core . You can use :

```
string[] urlSegments = new Uri(Request.GetDisplayUrl()).Segments;
```

`GetDisplayUrl()` is an extension method from the following namespace : `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily achieve this with a simple `.Split()` like:

```
var stringArray = "stackoverflow.com/questions/57798723/fetch-url-segments".Split('/');
```

Outputs:

```
stringArray[0] // stackoverflow.com
stringArray[1] // questions
```