# How do I get the base path Server-Side in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

How do I get the base path/Uri on the server side of Blazor WASM?
In pages it's obvious -> `Navigationmanager.BaseUri`.

But I need to do the same in the backend. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Waht do you mean with  server side of Blazor WASM?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Let's say I need the base path in the program.cs of the ProjectName.Server

Comment: I don't think that you can get it in this level because the app doesn't know any thing about the domain yet, I mean no body request the page yet!

Comment: You have to get client information from HttpRequest. sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120222/get-raw-url-from-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest